# jQuery/Javascript Regex Issue

Tags: jquery, regex

```
  var text = "Aanval op Name (xxx|yyy) CXX"
  var parts = text.match(/(\w+)\s*\((\d+)\|(\d+)\)\s*(\w+)/);
  parts = parts.slice(1);
                            var Name = parts[0];
                            var XXX = parts[1];
                            var YYY = parts[2];
                            var CXX = parts[3];
```

However, text could be

```
  var text = "Aanval op My Name Has A Space (xxx|yyy) CXX"
```

And then my regex doens't get the correct name. Is there any way I could change the regex so this does work in all cases? (No matter how many spaces)?

Comment: Where is `\d+` in your input?

Comment: I think that's (xxx|yyy) part

Comment: Yeah I think it is too. I don't know too much about Regex...

Comment: Is it always two character strings with no spaces before the start of the name and then everything remaining (excluding leading and trailing space) before the open bracket is the name?  It would also be useful if your `var text =` contained characters of the correct class (your regex would not match what you've provided).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following regex may be what you're searching for:

```
/op\s(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)\s*\((\d+)\|(\d+)\)\s*(\w+)/ig
```

Check [this Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gP4kW3) fiddle to see the desired matches :)